# Jquery scroll position change anchor link color if reach to it's page section, one page website

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can see that i have specific numbers in each if statement. I want it to specifically change the text color of the visited/current/active anchor link. The height of the page will depend of it's width so, what's the solution for this?
sorry if you're confused what am i talking about. I can't communicate english perfectly XD

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ajayrexluega/pen/JKJjbz)

```
var bottomPage = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height();
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

if(scrollPos >= 300 && scrollPos <= 854){
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $('header nav ul li a[href="#about-nav"]').addClass('current');
}else if (scrollPos >= 855 && !bottomPage){
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $('header nav ul li a[href="#portfolio-scroll"]').addClass('current');
}else if (bottomPage){
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $('header nav ul li a[href="#contact-scroll"]').addClass('current');
}else {
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

Here's my new code. I think, it works perfectly.

```
  var bottomPage = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height();
  var about = $('div#about-nav').position();
  var aboutPos = about.top;
  var portfolio = $('div#portfolio-scroll').position();
  var portfolioPos = portfolio.top;

  if(scrollPos >= aboutPos && scrollPos < (portfolioPos - 1)){
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $('header nav ul li a[href="#about-nav"]').addClass('current');
  }else if (scrollPos >= (portfolioPos - 1) && !bottomPage){
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $('header nav ul li a[href="#portfolio-scroll"]').addClass('current');
  }else if (bottomPage){
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $('header nav ul li a[href="#contact-scroll"]').addClass('current');
  }else {
    $('header nav ul li a').removeClass();
  }
```